# Synchronization between two ListViews scroll lagging

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-view

I've been trying to achieve synchronization between two  ListViews but I can't seem to be able to make it work smoothly.

The idea is that  the listviews are aligned next to each other inside a LinearLayout. The rows of each listview can be very complex ( i.e. they may include several TextViews,
CheckBoxes, Spinners or Buttons). The data sets used for each ListView are obviously different, therefore the rows in the left listview can have different height compared to the rows 
in the right listview. What I want to do is make them have the same row height at the same position.

I managed to do that using the same adapter for both lists and introducing a mediator pattern. What it does now is before getView returns the view i call a method in my mediatator whcih 
pretty much does the following:

row number 3 in LV1 needs to be drawn.
android draws it and determines that it needs to be 40 pixels high.
right before it's returned i call my mediator which checks the height of the same row ( i keep a reference of the two adapter instances in the mediator) position in the second listview and returns  that it's 70 pixels.
i set the height of row number 3 in LV1 to 70 and redraw it.

The problem is that whenever it needs to draw a new row it does a lot of work and there's an insane amount of calls to getView();
Also, when i change the height of a row in one of the list views so it matches the other, i force a complete redraw of all visible children in that listview which adds even more lag.

My question is -  is my concept totally wrong? Am i missing something here? Is there an easier way to do what i want to?

```
        |        LV 1         |   |         LV 2        | 
        |         1           |   |          1          |    
        |         2           |   |          2          |  
        |         3           |   |          3          | 
        |         4           |   |          4          | 
        |         5           |   |          5          |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a row heights array and store the maximum height of the two rows there in the first getView call. Then for the other times just get the height of each row from that array.

```
int [] rowHeight = new int[rowCount];
boolean firstTime = true;
```

then in your getView method:

```
if(firstTime){
    if(rowHeight[position] < currentView.getHeight()){
           rowHeight[position] = currentView.getHeight();
    }
}else{
    currentView.setHeight() = rowHeight[position];
}
```

Note: I didn't search for the exact methods so you can take the codes above as pseudo codes.

Comment: the problem is that when i change the height of a view at runtime all visible views get redrawn and  it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Or you should preCalculate all the values and set a standard height

Comment: Then you should calculate this before notifying the adapter and then when you get all the values start drawing